# Configuring htaccess for url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying hard to rewrite this URL

```
http://localhost/sitecms/?search=viewPage&pageId=1
```

TO

```
http://localhost/sitecms/pages/page/1
```

N.B. Variable 'search' declared at the top inside index.php, viewPage as function declared inside index.php receives pageId variable, and pass to viewPage.php inside another folder(template) along with associated data.

Below is my `.htaccess` code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ ?search=viewPage&pageId=$1 [L]
```

It's not working.

Suggestions are highly welcome about what I missed.

Comment: Could you please do confirm if you are hitting `http://localhost/sitecms/?search=viewPage&pageId=1` in browser and you want it to redirect to `http://localhost/sitecms/pages/page/1` in browser?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks. Not redirecting to any location. Just rewrite the url.

Comment: What is location of your .htaccess file?

Comment: "rewrite this URL `http://localhost/sitecms/?search=viewPage&pageId=1` TO `http://localhost/sitecms/pages/page/1`" - It's the other way round, you are "rewriting" from `/sitecms/pages/page/1` to `/sitecms/?search=viewPage&pageId=1`. However, `/sitecms/?search=viewPage&pageId=1` is not strictly a valid endpoint, as it would require further rewrites/subrequests to work. What is the actual file that handles the request?

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks. Actual file is index.php as controller wherein viewPage declared as function which accept the page id, and send associated data to a template file.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
##This rule redirects from http://localhost/sitecms/?search=viewPage&pageId=1 TO http://localhost/sitecms/pages/page/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(sitecms)/\?search=viewPage&pageId=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/pages/page/%2? [R=301,NE,L]

##Rules for handling non-existing files/directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(sitecms)/(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*)/(\d+)/?$ $1/?search=viewPage&PageId=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Nice solution +1, although it looks like you've got a (typo) the wrong slash... `\s\(sitecms)` should be `\s(/sitecms)` (or `\s/(sitecms)` and include a slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` substitution).

Comment: @RavinderSingh My browser showing 500 internal server error.

Comment: @MrWhite, Thank you for letting know, that's a GREAT catch, I have fixed it now cheers :)

Comment: @hossain, Could you please do provide more details like which sample url you are hitting?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 http://localhost/sitecms/?search=viewPage&pageId=1

Comment: @hossain, I did one minor change to Rules now, Please do update your htaccess file and clear your browser cache and test it again, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 When I click the link. the browser goes to http://localhost/E:/webdirs/sitecms/sitecms/pages/page/1 
Thanks

Comment: @hossain, yes I believe that was expected right? Please confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry. Not that was expected. I see no content but a 403 forbidden page

Comment: @hossain, ok try changing FROM `RewriteRule ^ %1/pages/page/%2? [R=301,NE,L]` -----> `RewriteRule ^  /%1/pages/page/%2? [R=301,NE,L]` AND FROM `RewriteRule ^(sitecms)/(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*)/(\d+)/?$ $1/?search=viewPage&PageId=$2 [NC,L]` ------> `RewriteRule ^(sitecms)/(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*)/(\d+)/?$  /$1/?search=viewPage&PageId=$2 [NC,L]` once? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 That also not working. Same result

Comment: @hossain, Ok, I have updated my answer now. Could you please do check it once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230757/discussion-between-hossain-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I said rewriting ul is working. but I do not want browser check for file at rewritten location.

Comment: @hossain, Thanks for confirmation. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` rules are NOT for file's existance they are for handling non-existing stuff(like mentioned in my solution's comments).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I wanted to rewrite url not for redirecting browser to a different location but for displaying a clean url. That's not happenning.

Comment: @hossain, sorry its not clear, could you please explain it more by giving examples here. Like--> `http://localhost:80/blabla` TO `http://localhost:80/etc` these are just examples just let me know in this form I will understand it better.

Comment: @hossain The rule should work as expected. Try clearing your browser cache or try a different browser to test the redirection.

Comment: This does assume the `.htaccess` file is being placed in the document root. However, the directive the OP posted in the question suggests they are placing the `.htaccess` file inside the `/sitecms` subdirectory?

Comment: @hossain, Hello, could you please confirm the location of your htaccess file? Where it is residing right now? Thank you.

Comment: @MrWhite You are right. My .htaccess file is placed inside /sitecms subdirectory at local server i.e. localhost.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 My .htaccess file is placed inside /sitecms subdirectory at local server i.e. localhost.

Comment: @hossain, Thanks for confirming the same, could you please try placing it one level before sitecms folder/directory? And try then, let me know how it goes then?

Comment: @hossain, please do let me know updates on this one, really excited to see how it goes for you :)